# How are TeX/LaTeX projects funded?

Tags: tex-history

One cannot avoid seeing the huge amount of work being done by people around the world to develop packages, classes, and even projects which dwarf LaTeX in terms of software complexity, and hence, in terms of time.

Time is money. Who pays for these people's time? Some are volunteers, sure. Some are scholars, some work for publishing houses, and others may be labeled as zealot geniuses.

Concretely, the question is:

- What are the major projects being developed these days?
  (LaTeX3? TikZ? Bidi? tcolorbox? Did I miss anything?)
- How are these projects being funded? (Donations? Scholarly organizations?)

Comment: See https://www.tug.org/tc/devfund/ and http://www.dante.de/index/Projekte.html.  All the projects you mentioned are developed by volunteers in their spare time.  The funded projects are mostly fonts or engine development.

Comment: I don't see how this is on-topic.

Comment: @cfr Borderline I agree, but we have other 'policy' and 'history' questions. I guess that it might be easier to answer if focussed on _e.g._ TeX itself and Lamport's LaTeX work, as both are historical and self-contained. I agree that an open-ended question about 'all packages' is challenging!

Comment: Feel free to edit the question as you may like. I am interested more in large packages such as bidi/tcolorbox/beamer etc.

Comment: I think it should be off topic. Mostly the answer is it's not funded and done by volunteers. (even for the latex core, the funding only covers the occasional travel money for face to face meetings, and buying tugboat, all actual latex development time is volunteer labour)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That sounds like the proper answer such that we can move on, instead discussing the question type. 14 votes on a off-topic question is the strange part. So apparently there is some interest regardless justified or not

Comment: @percusse No I won't answer (I voted to close) I have no idea how other projects are funded  other than the ones I am involved in, and I do not think this is a good forum for discussing people's finances.

Comment: As @JosephWright said, I think if the question were about TeX itself, or about the years of LaTeX development until some year, then it would be a history question, capable of being answered (or not) with publicly available information. (Still, “it wasn't funded” isn't a very interesting answer.) As it stands, it's asking about an arbitrary set (and number) of projects; I don't think there's any meaningful way of answering it — the “What are the major projects being developed these days” part alone makes it iffy, not to mention the awkwardness of discussing how other people get money (or not).

Comment: As to the question "What are the major projects being developed these days?", the answer is simple: my packages, of course ;-). Now, seriously, there are quite a few interesting projects and what "major " means depends on many factors.